# Plotting datasets using ErrorListPlot

Tags: plotting, dataset

I am trying to make list plots with the ErrorListPlot function. I have two datasets (ds1 and ds2) of which one plots nicely (ds1) and the other just give blank plots. I cannot see any difference in the way the datasets are set up so I am puzzled about why there should be any difference between them. I get no error message.

Here is my code:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ds1 = Dataset[{
<|"Sample" -> 1, "variable" -> "variable1", "mean" -> 1.`, 
 "min" -> 0.7662`, "max" -> 1.3051`|>, <|"Sample" -> 1, 
 "variable" -> "variable2", "mean" -> 0.0202`, "min" -> 0.011`, 
 "max" -> 0.0371`|>, <|"Sample" -> 1, "variable" -> "variable3", 
 "mean" -> 0.0001`, "min" -> 0.0001`, 
 "max" -> 0.0002`|>, <|"Sample" -> 2, "variable" -> "variable1", 
 "mean" -> 1.`, "min" -> 0.9368`, 
 "max" -> 1.0674`|>, <|"Sample" -> 2, "variable" -> "variable2", 
 "mean" -> 0.0511`, "min" -> 0.0431`, 
 "max" -> 0.0606`|>, <|"Sample" -> 2, "variable" -> "variable3", 
 "mean" -> 0.0001`, "min" -> 0.`, 
 "max" -> 0.0001`|>, <|"Sample" -> 3, "variable" -> "variable1", 
 "mean" -> 1.`, "min" -> 0.665`, 
 "max" -> 1.5038`|>, <|"Sample" -> 3, "variable" -> "variable2", 
 "mean" -> Missing["NA"], "min" -> Missing["NA"], 
 "max" -> Missing["NA"]|>, <|"Sample" -> 3, 
 "variable" -> "variable3", "mean" -> 0.2117`, "min" -> 0.1521`, 
 "max" -> 0.2947`|>}];

ds2 = Dataset[
{<|"Sample" -> 1, "variable" -> "variable1", "mean" -> 1.`, 
 "min" -> 0.8506`, "max" -> 1.1756`|>, <|"Sample" -> 1, 
 "variable" -> "variable2", "mean" -> 0.0277`, "min" -> 0.0196`, 
 "max" -> 0.0392`|>, <|"Sample" -> 1, "variable" -> "variable3", 
 "mean" -> 0.0001`, "min" -> 0.`, 
 "max" -> 0.0002`|>, <|"Sample" -> 2, "variable" -> "variable1", 
 "mean" -> 1.`, "min" -> 0.3085`, 
 "max" -> 3.2415`|>, <|"Sample" -> 2, "variable" -> "variable2", 
 "mean" -> 0.0326`, "min" -> 0.0127`, 
 "max" -> 0.0836`|>, <|"Sample" -> 2, "variable" -> "variable3", 
 "mean" -> 0.`, "min" -> 0.`, "max" -> 0.0002`|>, <|"Sample" -> 3,
  "variable" -> "variable1", "mean" -> 1.`, "min" -> 0.6651`, 
 "max" -> 1.5034`|>, <|"Sample" -> 3, "variable" -> "variable2", 
 "mean" -> 0.0164`, "min" -> 0.0112`, 
 "max" -> 0.024`|>, <|"Sample" -> 3, "variable" -> "variable3", 
 "mean" -> 0.0001`, "min" -> 0.`, 
 "max" -> 0.0002`|>, <|"Sample" -> 4, "variable" -> "variable1", 
 "mean" -> 1.`, "min" -> 0.4146`, 
 "max" -> 2.412`|>, <|"Sample" -> 4, "variable" -> "variable2", 
 "mean" -> 0.0437`, "min" -> 0.0222`, 
 "max" -> 0.0858`|>, <|"Sample" -> 4, "variable" -> "variable3", 
 "mean" -> 0.0057`, "min" -> 0.0017`, 
 "max" -> 0.0188`|>, <|"Sample" -> 5, "variable" -> "variable1", 
 "mean" -> 1.`, "min" -> 0.768`, 
 "max" -> 1.302`|>, <|"Sample" -> 5, "variable" -> "variable2", 
 "mean" -> 0.0261`, "min" -> 0.02`, 
 "max" -> 0.0339`|>, <|"Sample" -> 5, "variable" -> "variable3", 
 "mean" -> 0.`, "min" -> 0.`, "max" -> 0.`|>, <|"Sample" -> 6, 
 "variable" -> "variable1", "mean" -> 1.`, "min" -> 0.6516`, 
 "max" -> 1.5348`|>, <|"Sample" -> 6, "variable" -> "variable2", 
 "mean" -> Missing["NA"], "min" -> Missing["NA"], 
 "max" -> Missing["NA"]|>, <|"Sample" -> 6, 
 "variable" -> "variable3", "mean" -> 0.317`, "min" -> 0.23`, 
 "max" -> 0.4369`|>}];

varList = DeleteDuplicates[ds1[All, "variable"]] // Normal;

ds1[GroupBy[#variable &], 
  ErrorListPlot[
    Style[{{#, #2}, ErrorBar[{-(# - #3), (#4 - #)}, 0]}] & @@@ #, 
    Frame -> True,
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[.015]}] &,
  {"mean", "Sample", "min", "max"}] /@ varList
```

And this is the results:

Dataset 1: I get one plot like this for each sample, displaying points with error-bars.

[image]

Dataset2: I get one plot like this for each sample, displaying blank grids.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on what is going on with dataset 2?
Thanks!

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for the comment! I have changed my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remove `Style` everything seems to work:

```
ds2[GroupBy[#variable &], 
  ErrorListPlot[{{#, #2}, ErrorBar[{-(# - #3), (#4 - #)}, 0]} & @@@ #, Frame -> True, 
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[.015]}] &, {"mean", 
   "Sample", "min", "max"}] /@ varList
```

[image]

It wasn't doing anything (good) anyway so just leave it out.